# JQuery Mobile text input does not focus

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile and Javascript in general, so I am trying to learn it by doing a project. I am using JQuery mobile to design a web app and I require a few text inputs. In the JQuery documentation, there are text input examples that have a blue halo when they are clicked, and when the mouse moves away, the blue halo vanishes as well. I copied the provided code, but my text box does not have the same effect. I then tried inspecting the elements in the documentation and I realized that when the text box was clicked, the text input element gained an attribute called "ui-focus". How is this done?

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
</head>

<body style class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <label for="basic">Email:</label>

        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""/>
        </div>

        <label for="basic">Password:</label>

        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Another note, you don't need the last style sheet _structure_ unless you're using your own themes made by ThemeRoller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have copied rendered HTML code. JQM wraps `input` with a div to give it a new look. You don't have to add any extra code, only `input` tag, JQM will take care of the rest.

```
<input type="text" />
```